# Tkinter: How to check if a child window with title is opened

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a chatroom. In my code, I open a login window, and a user window. Then I choose the username from a listbox and then click `Start Chat` in class`MainScreen`

In my temporarily attempt, after click that button, it should create a child window with a tithe with `username`. That is, if I choose "A" "B" and "C" in the `listbox2`, it should open three windows with titles "A" "B" and "C"

However, I don't want to open two window with the same title. If I choose a username which has already used in the window title, it should just pull that window to the front.

I know there is a function can just check if a child window exists. But it can't detect the title of windows. These windows have the same instance(Do I describe it right?) but different titles in the function `ChatScreen`. So what should I do?

My code doesn't work exactly what I describe because I just make the temporarily code. I just want to know how to detect if the window is open by detecting the title first, then I can change my code.

Thanks for any help!

```
from Tkinter import *
import socket

########HelperFunction########
def chunkstring (block):    #Use to make the block into chunks and count the sum of ASCII value of chunks
    M = []
    for i in range(0, 512, 32):
        L = str((block[0 + i : 32 + i]))
        sum = 0
        for r in range(len(L)):
            sum = sum + ord(L[r])
        M.append(sum)
    return M

def leftrotate(x, c):
    return (x << c) & 0xFFFFFFFF | (x >> (32 - c) & 0x7FFFFFFF >> (32 - c))



########Connection########
def StartConnection (IPAddress, PortNumber):    #Use to set up the connection between computers and servers
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((IPAddress, PortNumber))
    return s

def login (s, username, password):    #Login Function
    print username
    print password
    s.send('LOGIN ' + username + '\n')
    data = s.recv(512)
    List = data.split(" ")    #send the commend and get something back

    CH = List[2]    # pick up the CHALLENGE code
    CH = CH[:-2]    # delete the last two unnecessary code
    PD = password
    message = PD + CH    # combine password and CHALLENGE together
    block = message + "1"

    block = block + "0" * (512 - len(message) - 3 - 1)    # add '0' to block and remain the space for last three digits

    numLen = len(str(len(message)))

    if numLen == 2:    #If the password is very long, we should consider the last digits may be affected
        block = block + "0" + str(len(message))
    elif numLen == 3:
        block = block + str(len(message))

    M = chunkstring(block)

    ########## MD5
    P = [7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22,
         5, 9, 14, 20, 5, 9, 14, 20, 5, 9, 14, 20, 5, 9, 14, 20,
         4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23,
         6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21]

    K = [0xd76aa478, 0xe8c7b756, 0x242070db, 0xc1bdceee,
         0xf57c0faf, 0x4787c62a, 0xa8304613, 0xfd469501,
         0x698098d8, 0x8b44f7af, 0xffff5bb1, 0x895cd7be,
         0x6b901122, 0xfd987193, 0xa679438e, 0x49b40821,
         0xf61e2562, 0xc040b340, 0x265e5a51, 0xe9b6c7aa,
         0xd62f105d, 0x02441453, 0xd8a1e681, 0xe7d3fbc8,
         0x21e1cde6, 0xc33707d6, 0xf4d50d87, 0x455a14ed,
         0xa9e3e905, 0xfcefa3f8, 0x676f02d9, 0x8d2a4c8a,
         0xfffa3942, 0x8771f681, 0x6d9d6122, 0xfde5380c,
         0xa4beea44, 0x4bdecfa9, 0xf6bb4b60, 0xbebfbc70,
         0x289b7ec6, 0xeaa127fa, 0xd4ef3085, 0x04881d05,
         0xd9d4d039, 0xe6db99e5, 0x1fa27cf8, 0xc4ac5665,
         0xf4292244, 0x432aff97, 0xab9423a7, 0xfc93a039,
         0x655b59c3, 0x8f0ccc92, 0xffeff47d, 0x85845dd1,
         0x6fa87e4f, 0xfe2ce6e0, 0xa3014314, 0x4e0811a1,
         0xf7537e82, 0xbd3af235, 0x2ad7d2bb, 0xeb86d391]

    #Initialize variables
    a0 = 0x67452301
    b0 = 0xefcdab89
    c0 = 0x98badcfe
    d0 = 0x10325476
    A = a0
    B = b0
    C = c0
    D = d0

    #Mainloop
    for i in range(0, 64):
        if i >= 0 and i <= 15:
            F = (B & C) | ((~ B) & D)
            F = F & 0xFFFFFFFF
            g = i

        elif i >= 16 and i <= 31:
            F = (D & B) | ((~ D) & C)
            F = F & 0xFFFFFFFF
            g = (5 * i + 1) % 16

        elif i >= 32 and i <= 47:
            F = B ^ C ^ D
            F = F & 0xFFFFFFFF
            g = (3 * i + 5) % 16

        elif i >= 48 and i <= 63:
            F = C ^ (B | (~ D))
            F = F & 0xFFFFFFFF
            g = (7 * i) % 16

        dTemp = D
        D = C
        C = B
        B = B + leftrotate((A + F + K[i] + M[g]), P[i])
        B = B & 0xFFFFFFFF
        A = dTemp

    #Add this chunk's hash to result so far:
    a0 = (a0 + A) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    b0 = (b0 + B) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    c0 = (c0 + C) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    d0 = (d0 + D) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    result = str(a0) + str(b0) + str(c0) + str(d0)

    s.send("LOGIN " + username + " " + result + "\n")    #send messagedigest to server
    reply = s.recv(512)
    print reply

    if "Successful" in reply:
        openMainScreen()
        return True
    else:
        First.quit()
        return False

def getUsers(s):
    s.send('@users')
    data = s.recv(512)
    data = data.split('@')    # use "@" help to split the list
    data = data[4:]    # start from the 4th element in order to avoid the elements I don't need
    return data

def getFriends(s):
    s.send('@friends')
    data = s.recv(512)
    data = data.split('@')
    data = data[4:]
    return data

def getRequests(s):
    s.send('@rxrqst')
    data = s.recv(512)
    data = data.split('@')
    data = data[3:]
    return data

def sendFriendRequest(s, friend):
    num = len(str(friend))    # count the len of my friends' name
    if 22 + num < 100:    # if it is short, so I can add three 0s
        size = '000' + str(22 + num)
    elif 22 + num >= 100:    # if it is long, I have to consider another situation
        size = '00' + str(22 + num)
    s.send('@' + size + '@request@friend@' + friend)
    data = s.recv(512)
    if "@ok" in data:
        SendRequestDialog()
        return True
    else:
        print False
        return False

def acceptFriendRequest(s, friend):
    num = len(str(friend))    # count the len of my friends' name
    if 21 + num < 100:    # if it is short, so I can add three 0s
        size = '000' + str(21 + num)
    elif 21 + num >= 100:     # if it is long, I have to consider another situation
        size = '00' + str(21 + num)
    s.send('@' + size + '@accept@friend@' + friend)
    data = s.recv(512)
    if "@ok" in data:
        Second.update()
        return True
    else:
        return False




########Interface#########
#--------Login--------#
class Login(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        First.geometry("250x250")
        self.lab1 = Label(frame, text = "Username")
        self.lab1.grid(row = 0, column = 125)
        self.ent1 = Entry(frame)
        self.ent1.grid(row = 1, column = 125)

        self.lab2 = Label(frame, text = "Password")
        self.lab2.grid(row = 2, column = 125)
        self.ent2 = Entry(frame, show = "*")
        self.ent2.grid(row = 3, column = 125)

        self.button = Button(frame, text = "OK", command = self.Submit)
        self.button.grid(row = 5, column = 125)

    def Submit(self):
        username = self.ent1.get()
        password = self.ent2.get()
        login(ss, username, password)

class MainScreen(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.lab1 = Label(frame, text = "All Users")
        self.lab1.grid(row = 1, column = 100)
        self.lab2 = Label(frame, text = "Your Friends")
        self.lab2.grid(row = 1, column = 300)
        self.lab3 = Label(frame, text = "Pending Requests")
        self.lab3.grid(row = 1, column = 500)
        self.button1 = Button(frame, text = "Send Request", command = self.SendRequest)
        self.button1.grid(row = 3, column = 100)
        self.button2 = Button(frame, text = "Start Chat", command = ChatScreen)
        self.button2.grid(row = 3, column = 300)
        self.button3 = Button(frame, text = "Accept Request", command = self.AcceptRequest)
        self.button3.grid(row = 3, column = 500)

        users = getUsers(ss)
        self.listbox1 = Listbox(frame)
        self.listbox1.grid(row = 2, column = 100)
        for item in users:
            self.listbox1.insert(END, item)
        self.value1 = str((self.listbox1.get(ACTIVE)))

        friends = getFriends(ss)
        self.listbox2 = Listbox(frame)
        self.listbox2.grid(row = 2, column = 300)
        for item in friends:
            self.listbox2.insert(END, item)

        requests = getRequests(ss)
        self.listbox3 = Listbox(frame)
        self.listbox3.grid(row = 2, column = 500)
        for item in requests:
            self.listbox3.insert(END, item)

    def SendRequest(self):
        friends = self.value1
        sendFriendRequest(ss, friends)

    def AcceptRequest(self):
        Accept = str((self.listbox3.get(ACTIVE)))
        num = self.listbox3.curselection()
        num = int(num[0])
        if acceptFriendRequest(ss, Accept) == True:
            self.listbox2.insert(END, Accept)
            self.listbox3.delete(num)

    def StartChat(self):
        global chatguy
        chatguy = str((self.listbox2.get(ACTIVE)))



def ChatScreen():
    aaa = Toplevel(First)
    aaa.title("aaa1")
    aaa.geometry("300x200")


def SendRequestDialog():
    Third = Toplevel(First)
    Third.title("Send Successfully")
    Third.geometry("300x100")
    lab = Label(Third, text = "The friend request was successfully sent")
    lab.pack()

def openMainScreen():
    global Second
    Second = Toplevel(First)
    Second.title("Chat with Client")
    Second.geometry("600x400")
    mainscreen = MainScreen(Second)

First = Tk()
First.title("Login")
LoginScreen = Login(First)
ss = StartConnection("86.36.34.215", 15112)
First.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `First` is the parent of all your windows in the widget tree, you can check the children of `First` to detect already open windows. Something like this:

```
for key,val in First.children.iteritems():
    if isinstance(val, tk.Toplevel):
        print("window: " + val.title())

#or to get a list of all titles
titles = map(lambda win:win.title() , filter(lambda w : isinstance(w, tk.Toplevel), First.children.itervalues()))
if title not in titles:
    #...
```